# How to get the return type of a lambda, reduce function in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to implement a reduce function but I don't know how to take the return type of the lambda:

```
template <typename IT, typename F, typename OT = IT>
auto reducef(const IT& input, F func) -> decltype(func(IT::value_type))
{
    decltype(func(typename IT::value_type)) result = {}; 
    return std::accumulate(input.begin(), input.end(), result, func);
}
```

Compiler output is the following:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cpp:37:80: error: no matching function for call to ‘reducef(std::vector<int>&, main(int, char**)::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>)’
test.cpp:37:80: note: candidate is:
test.cpp:22:6: note: template<class IT, class F, class OT> decltype (func(IT:: value_type)) reducef(const IT&, F)
test.cpp:22:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class IT, class F, class OT> decltype (func(IT:: value_type)) reducef(const IT&, F) [with IT = std::vector<int>; F = main(int, char**)::<lambda(const int&, const int&)>; OT = std::vector<int>]’:
test.cpp:37:80:   required from here
test.cpp:22:6: error: dependent-name ‘IT:: value_type’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type
test.cpp:22:6: note: say ‘typename IT:: value_type’ if a type is meant
```

Extended use case:

```
template <typename IT, typename F, typename OT = IT>
OT mapf(const IT& input, F func)
{
    OT output;
    output.resize(input.size());
    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), output.begin(), func);
    return output;
}

template <typename IT, typename F, typename OT = IT>
auto reducef(const IT& input, F func) -> decltype(func(IT::value_type))
{
    typename IT::value_type result = {};
    return std::accumulate(input.begin(), input.end(), result, func);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    auto v2 = mapf(v1, [](const int& i) { return i+1;});
    for (const auto& i : v2)
    {     
        cout << i << endl;  
    }   
    cout << reducef(v1, [](const int& i, const int& j) -> int { return i + j; }) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Did you really mean `()` after `result`? And what's the problem you're encountering?

Comment: Just trying to default construct result...

Comment: @piotr, then use `{}`, otherwise you are declaring a function.

Comment: It seems you are missing a `typename` in multiple places refering to `IT::value_type`.

Comment: Please post an actual testcase. Those line numbers are not helpful.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes  So int a = {}; default initializes a? I'm trying to find this on the standard without much success.

Comment: @piotr look for list-initialization, 8.5.4, if I am not mistaken (oh gosh, why did I memorize that? Now excuse me while I go out to see a doctor)

Comment: Using the default value of (some type) for the initial value of `std::accumulate` seems incredibly limiting to me, since many (if not most) binary operators on `T` are likely to have left identity values which differ from the default construction. For example, consider `sum`, `product`, `max`, `min`, `and` and `or` on integers; only two of those will work with an initial value of `0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want to declare you return type as something like

```
decltype(func(std::declval<typename IT::value_type>(),
              std::declval<typename IT::value_type>()))
```

Here is a complete testcase:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

template <typename IT, typename F, typename OT = IT>
auto reducef(const IT& input, F func)
    -> decltype(func(std::declval<typename IT::value_type>(),
                     std::declval<typename IT::value_type>()))
{
    decltype(func(std::declval<typename IT::value_type>(),
                  std::declval<typename IT::value_type>())) result{};
    return std::accumulate(input.begin(), input.end(), result, func);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values;
    reducef(values, [](int a, int b) { return a + b; });
}
```

Comment: Dietmar: if that were sufficient, it would be unnecessary because the return type of func must be the type of its first argument (see the definition of `std::accumulate`). But the OP attempts to supply an initial value which is default-constructed from the return type. I think that's totally wrong-headed, but anyway it cannot be deduced  because C++ cannot solve `T = decltype(func(T(), V()))` (and indeed there may be an infinite number of solutions).

Comment: Even when using `std::result_of` you'd still need to pull out the type of the values. Thinking of it, I think the above code could do without `std::declval<T>()`, though: `func(*input.begin(), *input.begin())` would do as well. It's still nice to demo `std::declval<T>()`, though ;)

Comment: @rici: what exactly doesn't work about my solution using either `std::declval<T>()` or `*input.begin()` to get an instance of the argument within `decltype()`? Also, the return type of `std::accumulate()` happens to be the type of its third argument and who knows what `func(*it, *it)` returns! ... but the compiler can deduce it. In fact, it has to be cause it won't get anything better when calling the function object in the first place.

Comment: Your solution works fine if the function's prototype is something like `V func(V, V)`, but `std::accumulate` doesn't require that: it requires `U func(U, V)`. OP tries to compute `U` by finding the type of `func(U)` (although he means `func(U, V)`) but that's not deducible because you can't get the type of `func(U, V)` without knowing `U`, so you can't deduce `U` that way. If `U` == `V`, then there is no problem, but that restricts the possible uses of `reducef` (eg. `reducef(v, [](std::ostream& o, const T& t){return o << v;}`)

Comment: Dietmar, the other thing was that if you know that func takes two arguments of the same type, you don't have to deduce the return type because it must be compatible with the argument type (since that's what `std::accumulate` requires). So you can just use the argument type as a return type.

Comment: The argument type can be `char` and the lambda could be `[](int a, int b) { return a + b; }`. If I'd use `char` as the result I would often get a rather different result...

Comment: However, I agree that there are limitations on what can be deduced. If the first function argument isn't deduced itself, something like this could be used to satisfy it: `struct whatever { operator T&() const; };`.